# Providing the reference list on an interview prematurely

Tags: interviewing

I'm currently between jobs and I'm interviewing at least once a week. The last interview I had went well but towards the end of the interview my nerves did a number on me and I provided my reference list without being asked for it. First time I've been so nervous, worried on what the outcome would be? Would they see past this?

Comment: I'm not a hiring manager but I'd be really surprised if they viewed this negatively.

Answer (score 4):

**RELAX**

This is a non-issue.  A good interviewer will add your references list to the folder where they keep your resume and any interview notes.

Everyone gets "interview jitters" once in a while.